# Slick: get table name

Tags: slick-3.0

With a table definition like this one:

```
class Test(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[TestRow](_tableTag, "test") { ... }
```

how can I get back the table name (Tag "test") from an instance of `Test`?

The thing is I can perfectly execute some queries like `db run TableQuery[Test].result`, but to write raw sql, I need the table name.

Comment: `myTableQuery.baseTableRow.tableName`?

Comment: @insan-e Yes, thanks! You can add it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at Slick's [`TableQuery` ScalaDoc](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/api/index.html#slick.lifted.TableQuery) there is a method called `baseTableRow` which says:

> `def baseTableRow: E`
>
> Get the "raw" table row that **represents the table itself**, as opposed
>   to a Path for a variable of the table's type. This method should
>   generally not be called from user code.

So you go to `E <: AbstractTable`'s "definition" (`AbstractTable`) [Scaladoc](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/api/index.html#slick.lifted.AbstractTable) and find what you need, namely `val tableName: String`. The trick here is to know where to look (possible implicit conversions and other stuff...), that is, how to navigate the Scala(Doc) rabbithole. xD